# How to import opencv into python project using spyder in Mac?

Tags: python, macos, opencv, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to use OpenCV in a Python project in Spyder, I wanted to know if there is any way to install it as a package in spyder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error message it stated:

> python 3.6* Use "conda info " to see the dependencies for
>   each package"

It looks that you are using `Python 3.6` in your MAC machine. The `conda install` command below will get the `OpenCV 3.2.0` for `64-bit OSX` for you which is just released two days ago in `conda-forge` repository [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv).

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv=3.2.0
```

The `menpo` repository [here](https://anaconda.org/menpo/opencv3) only has `OpenCV 3.1.0` for `Python 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5` for `osx-64` at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac. Open terminal.

conda install -c menpo opencv3

In windows.

1. Choose your distro, python ver and system at:
   [http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv)

And download the .whl to a folder of your choice.
For instance I chose the 5th from the bottom of the opencv list because I have python 3.6 on a 64 bit OS.

2. Open command prompt, go to the folder, and type

   pip install opencv(ver).whl

Where (Ver) indicates the file you just downloaded.

Run python and try and import cv2. If it works you succeeded.

Comment: It gives following error:
`UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - opencv3 -> python 2.7* -> openssl 1.0.1*
  - python 3.6*
Use "conda info <package>" to see the dependencies for each package.`